# log-log regression in r

Tags: r, regression, logarithm

I want to do a log-log regression in R.
I managed to do a simple linear and log-linear regression by using this code:

```
lm <- lm(Price ~ ., data=data_price2)
lm2 <- lm(log(Price) ~ ., data=data_price2)
```

Now, I want to do a log-log regression, but I can't find out how to add the independent variables in the logarithmic form. Some of these independent variables are dummy variables.
If I add them individually after the '~' in the equation, R gives me this error:

```
lm4 <- lm(log(Price) ~ log(nbrCores)+ log(nbrSims) + log(CameraBack), data = data_price2)
```

**Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'**

I have about 140 independent variables, so I prefer not to add them manually.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: (Although this appears to be an [off topic] question about how to use R, this is based, in part, on a statistical confusion that we can clear up. I think this should stay open here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to  take care if you pass **zero** to a `log` function. Avoid this procedure.

You can use a `map` function and use `log` to only **variable with factors >0.**

However you don't need to apply `log` to all variable of the function. You only need to apply `log` to the target.

Answer (score 4):

If you have dummies, it is likely you coded them as "factors" (categorial) in your data with R. But logarithm of categorial variable is not defined.
See this R code

```
log(factor("a"))
Error in Math.factor(factor("a")) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors
Called from: Math.factor(factor("a"))
```

If you have done dummy coding yourself, it is likely it is based on numeric data in R. And thus, you will most likely have 0's in your data. The logarithm of 0 is -Inf, see also this R code:

```
log(0)
-Inf
```

And this is exactly what the error message is telling you. Most likely, not all your data is suitable for a log transformation.